# Javascript map strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I was resolving some problems on codewars and tried to convert a string to a list of numbers like this:

```
"102904".split("").map(parseInt);
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
[1, 0, 2, 9, 0, 4]
```

But it returns instead:

```
[1, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 4]
```

At believe that map should apply to each element in the list which are strings of 1 digits. One could believe that it isn't parsing correctly because the base isn't used but:

```
"102904".split("").map(function(x){ return parseInt(x);});
[ 1, 0, 2, 9, 0, 4]
```

Using `parseInt(x, 10)`, doesn't change the result. But sending directly parseInt to map creates `NaN`...

I tried on Chrome and Firefox and I receive the same results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `"102904".split("").map(function(x){ return parseInt(x);});` appears to return the expected result in Chrome 30.

Comment: Yeah, I'd delete it but SO tells me that I can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function provided as the callback to [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) receives three arguments:

- the element from the array
- the index in the array
- the array itself

If you provide two arguments to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the second is treated as the radix – the numerical base to parse the number in. So you string is parsed like this

```
string | base | result
----------------------
1      | 0    | 1
0      | 1    | NaN
2      | 2    | NaN
9      | 3    | NaN
0      | 4    | 0
4      | 5    | 4
```

The surprising behaviour here is that using base `0` (which is impossible), the result is `1` rather than `NaN`. This is because `parseInt` treats a radix of `0` as if it were not provided:

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following: [(MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: yep I forgot about that map sends 3 parameters.

Answer (score 7):

`parseInt` involves second argument - radix.

Your problem is that - `map` sends to arguments: item itself and index.

Problem digits are: `0, 2, 9`

Why ?

- 0 - has radix passed as 1. 1 isn't a legal radix so `NaN`
- 2 - has radix passed as 2. In 2 base 2 is not available digit(0 and 1
  are)
- 9 - has radix passed as 3. Still 9 is not a valid digit(0, 1 and 2
  are)

Answer (score 1):

```
"102904".split("").map(function(x, y){ console.log(x, y) });
```

returns

```
1 0
0 1
2 2
9 3
0 4
4 5
```

This means that, in your first example, `parseInt` gets called like this:

```
parseInt("1", 0);
parseInt("0", 1);
parseInt("2", 2);
parseInt("9", 3);
// ecc...
```

You're passing the index of the iteration as a second parameter to `parseInt()` (which represents the radix of the number to be parsed).

---

The best solution is to use the second approach, with the code you already posted.

Comment: Yes, I was in the kitchen and realized that js sends multiple params to map unlike other functional languages..